# How to change the brand word in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I change the word BRAND text in WooCommerce WordPress?
I have a website which features painting artists.
I am looking to use woocommerce brands plugins to use artists as brands,
but when you click on a brand (Artist) it shows something like this on the archive title:

Brand: Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to use the WordPress plugin [SEO Yoast](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/).

When installed and activated, go to: **Yoast SEO -> Search Appearance -> Taxonomies**. Then remove or rename the string 'Brand' from the SEO Title.

See attachment below. In your case it would be 'Brands'.

[image]